# How to get P5JS line to slide to new position on function mousePressed()

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, p5.js

I'm trying to make a jukebox animation using line as the records. I want

```
line(record1X1, 120, record1X2, 120);
```

to slide from (50, 120, 170, 120) to (375, 120, 475, 120) in my p5js sketch. I got it to work by putting

```
if (record1X2 < 475 && record1X1 < 375 ) {

    record1X1 += recordSpeed;

    record1X2 += recordSpeed;
}
```

(recordSpeed is equal to 2)

in function draw(), but I want the animation to happen on function mousePressed() on an ellipse in my drawing. I tried to use a for loop in mousePressed() to get it to work, but it just makes the line jump into place instead of having a smooth transition. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop inside the `mousePressed()` function won't work because only the last frame will show up. Instead, you need to do all your movement inside the `draw()` function.

You could do something like set a boolean variable inside the `mousePressed()` function, which you then use inside the `draw()` function. Something like this:

```
function draw(){
  if(mouseWasPressed){
    if (record1X2 < 475 && record1X1 < 375 ) {

      record1X1 += recordSpeed;

      record1X2 += recordSpeed;
    }
  }
}
```